# Form not getting submitted via AjaxForm/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, ajaxform

There is a table which displays items and has a "Delete" button in each row. The delete button is inside a form.
I'm using AjaxForm method to submit form. Clicking the delete button is supposed to delete the data without getting directed to any page or without refreshing current page. 
But what happens is form gets submitted in regular way as defined on action tag.

I'm displaying results on table in following way:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {               
    ?>  


<tr>
  <td><?php echo  ++$x; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["author"]; ?></td>
  <td>
  <form method="POST" id='deleteform' class="forms" action="deletebook.php">         
  <input type="hidden" name="deletebook" value='<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' >
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
  </form>
  </td>
</tr> 


<?php
    }
}

else
{
    echo "No Books Found!";
}
```

This displays table in following [way](http://postimg.org/image/myr68td1v/)

To submit the form via AjaxForm, it's been done as follows: (I haven't shown `<table>` tags here. pardon me.)

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#deleteform').ajaxForm(function() { 

                    alert("success");

                }); 
                event.preventDefault();
            }); 
    </script>
```

The problem is that form is submitted via regular way `action="deletebook.php"`
Trust me in other pages the form gets submitted via AjaxForm. But in this page, the problem is occuring.

Could this be happening because every "delete" button is a form displayed according to the contents in the table.
Please help me.

**EDIT:** The issue is not about being unable to delete data.The data was getting deleted before and is getting deleted now. Data is getting deleted by sending me to the `deletebook.php` page. I want data to get deleted without sending me to any other page.

Comment: `ajaxForm()` method? Is that part of a plugin? Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: this is invalid html. all delete buttons will have the same id.

Comment: you have `n` number of `id='deleteform'`, so which one do you want to bind with `$('#deleteform').ajaxForm(function() {`, as `id`s are supposed to be unique. classes will be your friend.

Comment: you're using event.preventDefault(), but event is not defined, check your console

Comment: @JayBlanchard sorry i'm newbie. Yes it is a jquery plugin. How do i watch response?

Comment: @marcel Data gets deleted by putting id. i want data to get deleted by pressing delete button without sending me to deletebook.php which is defined in action="deletebook.php".

Comment: @Sean i want to delete the particular row. it's working but i'm being navigated to deletebook.php which shouldnt happen. do i submit form by putting $('.form').ajaxForm(function()?

Comment: I am not familiar with your `ajaxForm` plug-in, but it might be possible if you just bind to all forms `$('form').ajaxForm(function()`

Comment: @Ruben i removed that. console says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajaxForm is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {               
    ?>  


<tr>
  <td><?php echo  ++$x; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row["author"]; ?></td>
  <td>
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenId" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
  </td>
</tr> 


<?php
    }
}

else
{
    echo "No Books Found!";
}

?>

<script>
    var id;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-danger").click(function(){
        id = $(this).prev().val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "deletebook.php",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                "deletebook": id
            }
        }).done(function(response){
            $(".hiddenId[value='" + id + "']").parent().parent().remove();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Add:

```
$('#addbook').ajaxForm(
{ 
    success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){
        $('#booksuccess').modal('show'); 
        $("#reset").click(); 
        $("tr").last().append(responseText);
    }
});
```

And in your php add method, return a string like this:

```
"<tr><td></td><td>1</td><td>$Title</td><td>$Author</td><td><input type=\"hidden\" class=\"hiddenId\" value=\"$Id\" /><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs\">Delete</button></td></tr>";
```

Comment: didnt work. btw the rows were getting deleted before. But after changing the code like you showed the rows arent getting deleted either.

Comment: Why not? I miss "document" keyword before "forms["deleteform"].submit()

I just updated the code above. And i tested it and works fine.

Comment: It worked but i'm back to square one now man! Data was getting deleted before correctly. It is getting deleted now too. What i want is that when i press the delete button, Data should be deleted without sending me to deletebook.php

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: My apologizes. Is this result that you are expecting?
http://nettechlab.info/teste.html

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez Yes! that is the result i'm expecting!! How do i do that?? Please help me!

Comment: I just updated the code above. I used $.ajax instead of ajaxForm. Can you test it again?

Comment: Thank u so much! That worked like a charm. btw in that same page i have a option to add books. do u have any idea how i could refresh only the table to show the new added books? by clicking a button?

Comment: Do you add by ajax too?
If yes, you can return a json object with the record added in the add ajax callback, and then insert it using jquery. It isn't hard to do.

Comment: If you need help, just put here the code block that is used to add new book

Comment: So the form that adds book has id "#addbook". I'm using AjaxForm to submit form.   `<script> 
   $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#addbook').ajaxForm(function() { 
   $('#booksuccess').modal('show');
   $("#reset").click();
   }); 
   event.preventDefault();
   }); 
        </script>`  when book gets added. a popup modal shows saying book added and the input fields get cleared. It's working good.

Comment: Hi @SulavDepp. I updated the code again. See at "Add:" line and following
Please, let me know if it works for you because to me it worked.

Comment: The problem is that im using different php page for adding book, displaying books on table and deleting book. I think ur code tries to bring "tr" from addbook.php. whereas the table including "tr" is at displaybook.php and deleting function is at deletebook.php. which make the situation kinda contradicting.

Comment: So, can you return a string with json structure from addbook.php ?

Comment: Wait, your ajax to add book is pointing to addbook.php? And if we use $.ajax again instead of ajaxForm to add books?
I think it would work. Can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the ajaxForm plugin here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#deleteform').ajaxForm(
           {
              beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options){
                   //show loader
              },
              success:function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) { 

                 alert(responseText);
                 //hide loader
              }
           }
        ); 

    });
```

Comment: Your answer successfully deletes the row. I could do that before i wanted a code to delete the row without sending me to another page. Thnx anyways.